# Error when trying to execute Microsoft Band sample code

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-8.1, microsoft-band

When trying to execute any of the Microsoft Band sample projects I always get the following error when trying to connect to the Band:

```
using 
(
IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0])
)
```

throws exception:

> An error occurred while attempting to aquire the Bluetooth device service. This error can occur if the paired device is unreachable or has become unpaired from the current host.

This is on a windows desktop by the way, windows throws up the control asking can it access my band I say allow and it throws the error, I have tried switching off the Bluetooth power management as suggested in the documentation but still no help.....

Also followed the advice here: [Microsoft Band SDK on Windows 8,1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148008/microsoft-band-sdk-on-windows-8-1) still no help....

Any ideas?

Comment: Was that desktop the last device to have been paired to the Band?  Does both the desktop and the Band show their Bluetooth status as 'connected'?  (On the Band, see if the Bluetooth icon to the left of the time is lit.)  Do you see the same behavior on any other device (if you have one)?  What kind of (Bluetooth) hardware is the desktop?

Comment: @PhilHoff--MSFT I have the same issue.  Same error on Windows 8.1 laptop and my Windows 10 development workstation with USB bluetooth dongle.  Windows says device is connected and so does the Band's bluetooth icon.

Comment: I finally got it to connect after unregistering and doing a factory reset (https://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-band/en-us/support/phone-app/reset) and a few more re-pairings and reboots... that was only on my Windows 10 machine, still no luck on my Windows 8.1 laptop.  Something with the whole Windows bluetooth is being really flaky.

Answer (score 0):

Have add the Bluetooth Capabilities in the manifest?

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="serviceId:A502CA9A-2BA5-413C-A4E0-13804E47B38F" />
    <Function Type="serviceId:C742E1A2-6320-5ABC-9643-D206C677E580" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```