# Connecting to Microsoft band via bluetooth on windows 8.1(desktop) return 0 instance

Tags: bluetooth, windows-store-apps, microsoft-band

I having problem to Microsoft band via bluetooth on windows 8.1(desktop). I had paired the band with the PC before running the sample app. The samples apps are from the band website. The BandClientManager keeps returning 0 instance when executing the app.  How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Band SDK on Windows 8,1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148008/microsoft-band-sdk-on-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try my answer from an earlier question ([Microsoft Band SDK on Windows 8,1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148008/microsoft-band-sdk-on-windows-8-1)) :

Re-pair the Band to the PC:
1.On the Band, go to the Settings tile and tap the Bluetooth icon, then change the Bluetooth state from "On" to "Pairing".
2.On the PC, go to the Bluetooth "Show Bluetooth Devices" and unpair the Band (if previously paired to the PC) and then start a fresh pairing.

Disable Power Saving on the PC's BT Adapter
1.On your PC, launch Device Manager (e.g. by right clicking the Windows 8.1 Start Button and choosing "Device Manager")
2.In Device Manager, go to Bluetooth -> and right click and select "Properties".
3.Go to the "Power Management" tab of the Properties dialog, and make sure that "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" checkbox is NOT checked.