# Connect Band 2 to a Windows 10 virtual machine via Bluetooth

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-10, hyper-v, microsoft-band

I'm trying to connect my Microsoft Band 2 to Windows 10 via bluetooth to start working through the sample projects given in the sdk, but I can't seem to get connected.

I've worked through all the solutions mentioned in the link below, but none seem to apply specifically to the Band 2. Any suggestions?
[Microsoft Band SDK on Windows 8,1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148008/microsoft-band-sdk-on-windows-8-1)

**Edit with Solution:**

The problem was caused because I was running my Windows app through a virtual machine and Bluetooth was shared between the host and the VM.  I fixed the problem by using a USB Bluetooth Adapter only available to the VM, restored my band to factory settings, paired it via USB to the Band app, then paired it to Bluetooth.  Now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

is your Band paired to your Windows machine? You have to pair it first. If it is, did you setup the app manifest for the BT device?

Comment: I paired it to my machine w/ the USB and Band Sync app and now have connected to bluetooth. I edited the app manifest in the sample heartrate Windows 8.1 project downloaded with the sdk, added <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest"> <Device Id="any"> <Function Type="serviceId:A502CA9A-2BA5-413C-A4E0-13804E47B38F" /> <Function Type="serviceId:C742E1A2-6320-5ABC-9643-D206C677E580" /> and proximity. The app recognizes the band, but it fails at `BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))`

Comment: Does your Band work with a mobile app? It has to have the latest firmware update in order to work with the SDK.

Comment: It works perfectly with the iPhone microsoft health app.  Though I reset it to factory settings before trying to connect it to my desktop

Comment: Does the pairedBands list contains any item? What kind of exception do you get?

Comment: Ok, I ended up fixing it. The problem was occurring because I'm using a virtual machine and even though I paired the Band using the Windows VM, it was still being recognized by the host machine, which apparently caused problems.  I purchased a usb Bluetooth dongle and had that be only recognized by the VM, and everything is working now.  Thanks!